# Changing Delphi 7 application title

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm forking a existing Delphi 7 application to a new name. I used "Save Project as" to create the new project. I also changed the COM automation typelib library and interface names and GUIDs. All this worked fine.

But after I changed the Application.Title (>Project>Options>Application Settings>Title) the application is showing a strange behavior: It runs normally, but the wait cursor keeps rolling after the application starts. Every thing else seems to work fine.

If I change the title to any other name, the problem goes away. Even adding an space in the end of the name solves the problem. The name is 6 characters long, all letters. No symbols, spaces or numbers. I'm puzzled.

What is the Application.Title used for, besides showing in the Windows footer and task manager ?

Comment: `Application.Title` is used exclusively to name the hidden window associated with the `Application` object.

Comment: I recall a weird problem many years back, possibly as far back as Win2k. A colleague created an application named "Language" (or similar) and it also behaved strangely. It turned out that this particular name conflicted with something in Windows. (Disclaimer: _This was a long time back and I don't recall the exact details. E.g. he may have also been trying to register it as a service. I just don't recall_.) The point is maybe there's something special about your particular app name that's causing your problem. Other than that there should be no problem!

Comment: @Craig, you should [`choose carefully`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22871043/960757) app. name these days as well, otherwise some users might be surprised.

Comment: @TLama That's the executable name rather than the window text of the hidden application window

Comment: @David, look what Craig wrote. It's been response to his comment.

Answer (score 5):

Application title used solely to display the title for the application in the windows taskbar. By default it has same text as the name of EXE file. You can change it dynamically like this

```
 Application.Title := 'two';
```

I confirmed it with the book "Delphi-7 second edition" writen by Homonenko Anatoly Dmitrievich. Even though it was written in Russian.

PS If you give me the word you used, I check it on my installation of Delphi-7 on Win-7x64

Comment: That's what I first thought: the title is just a name. But trying to give the title 'nassau' to an application started the strange behaviour.  With 'nassau ' or 'nassau_' it worked fine. I still don't understand why.

Comment: It works fine for my development environment, cursor is normal. BUT, I have an idea. My Delphi7 also behave strangely, it happens when I create a new application, put only one button on the form and compile it. The antivirus detects a virus in my freshly compiled application, saying it is a "TROJ_DOWNLOADER_00005ed.TOMA". Delphi says "Error - Could not find program, 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Delphi7SE\Projects\Project1.exe'". If I put any extra component on the form - it would work fine. Delphi itself and distributive does not have viruses. I think you have a similar "virus related" problem.